# How to simulate Wi-fi signal strength indoor environment?

Tags: wireless, wifi, network, simulation

I want to simulate Wi-fi signal strengths received by a mobile moving around in X m3 that contains N access points. I must take into account the effect of walls and if possible the effect of moving humans.

What tool can I use? Free if possible?

Comment: what does "X m2" mean? If it's meant to imply squaremetres, can it be assumed that this is in a place that doesn't have the regular three dimensions, maybe like in a cartoon?

Comment: I corrected this! Actually it's a 3-D but in my scenario, the moving mobile has fixed z coordinate.

Comment: netspot for windows http://download.cnet.com/NetSpot/3000-18508_4-76475846.html and much better for another thing
https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/ IBwave also

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood you. You will probably find [my other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106781/how-to-simulate-wi-fi-signal-strength-indoor-environment/106829#106829) more helpful.

If you are using an Apple product, (iPhone, iPad, Macbook etc.) you can use a free tool called Network Link Conditioner. You can download it from Apple's [developer website](https://developer.apple.com) although you need to register for a free account first. Then, you can use it to simulate just about any network conditions. Here is a screenshot of it on my mac:
[image: Network Link Conditioner]

It comes with lost of useful profiles, and creating your own is easy:
[image: Creating a profile]

To simulate it on a mobile device you use iPhone Simulator, also from Apple's developer website.

For Windows, check out [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com). I don't have access to a windows machine, so I can't show you how it works.

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) is an amazing web debugging proxy, runs on all platforms, and can simulate various network conditions, among many other features. Configuration is again, pretty simple:
[image: Charles throttling settings]

It's not free, but the 30 day free trial is fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about my last answer, I didn't read the question properly. [NetSpot](http://www.netspotapp.com) would seem to be the program you're looking for. It's free, but again, it's only for mac. Pretty easy to use:
[image: NetSpot screenshot 1]
[image: NetSpot screenshot 2]